# Mostrar saltos de linea al cargar variable en Vue

Tags: vuejs

**Forma de trabajo**

Se tiene un `<textarea v-model="descripcion" class="form-control" rows="2"></textarea>` se manda por axios para guardar en el servidor.

Se muestra de la forma `{{descripcion}}` traída de la base de datos por medio de axios.

Lo que se busca es que respete los saltos de linea que se dan antes de guardar y que muestre el texto de igual forma.

Se a intentado añadir con cada enter \n y/o `<br>` como texto a la variable, pero no a funcionado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podés usar la etiqueta [`<pre>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/pre) para mostrar el texto guardado con saltos de línea `\n`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    descripcion: 'Se a intentado \nañadir \\n con cada enter \ncomo texto a la variable'
  },
})
```

```css
textarea {
  width:100%;
}
pre {
  width:100%;
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <textarea v-model="descripcion" rows="5"></textarea>
  <br>
  <pre>{{descripcion}}</pre>
</div>
```

Con Bootstrap

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    descripcion: 'Se a intentado \nañadir \\n con cada enter \ncomo texto a la variable \ncon Bootstrap'
  },
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <textarea v-model="descripcion" rows="5" class="form-control"></textarea>
  <br>
  
  <pre>{{descripcion}}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias, esa fue la solución, en mi caso uso bootstrap, la etiqueta `<pre>` ya trae estilos predefinidos, es necesario resetearlos en el componente que se usará para mostrar los saltos de linea.